# $not operator in mongodb not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Im currently writing a nodejs web app that uses mongodb for all the database work. Im currently trying to run a query to remove all documents that match one criteria and not match another.

Here is the code:

```
{ $and:[ {name:"bob"}, { hair: { $not: "brown" } } ] }
```

However it returns

```
MongoError: invalid use of $not
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `$ne` instead:

```
{ hair: { $ne: "brown" } }
```

`$not` is used for logical disjunctions, not for field comparisons.